# Slow prediction in Google InceptionV-3 using Transfer learning

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am using Google's inceptionv-3 model and TensorFlow for gender recognition using Transfer Learning ( [here's the link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/) of the tutorial) On my data-set having 135 face images of female and 335 face images of male. After the training it shows 95% accuracy and I tested on few Images it's working fine but it's taking around 3 seconds for the classification result.

I am trying to do it in real time (live video feed)

Below is the code I modified it bit, I loaded the model first it took one seconds, then I make it in infinite loop so I just pass the image and get the prediction result.

```py
 import os, sys
 import tensorflow as tf
 os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
 import time

 # Unpersists graph from file
 with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
      graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
      tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

 # change this as you see fit
 image_path = sys.argv[1]

 # Read in the image_data
 image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

 # Loads label file, strips off carriage return
 label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
 in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]


 while True:
           start_time = time.time()
           with tf.Session() as sess:

                # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
                softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

                predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
                print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
                # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
                """top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

                for node_id in top_k:
                human_string = label_lines[node_id]
                score = predictions[0][node_id]"""
```

Here's the output:

```py
--- 2.21238899231 seconds ---
--- 2.1374540329 seconds ---
--- 2.08863019943 seconds ---
--- 2.08074688911 seconds ---
--- 2.07966399193 seconds ---
```

Is there any way I can reduce the time here, I am sorry about code formatting.
I am not sure if I have asked right question, I am very new to ML.

Thanks for the help!

sys config: AMD-A4, 2.5GHz, 8GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not recreate session from scratch in the loop. Create one session object, and during loop just call sess.run(...) over and over again. Also, you should call "get_tensor_by_name" only once (outside a loop). Apart from that nothing can be done code-wise. You could put the execution on the gpu to make things faster though.

Comment: I am able to do the prediction in 1.2 seconds with the changes as per your instructions. 
I am trying to do it in real time, I am extracting face from real time video using Opencv HaarCascade and passing it to `tf.gfile.FastGFile(face_resize, 'rb').read()`
It's throwing me an error
`TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array([[[255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0],
        ..., 
        [255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]]],dtype=unit8)`
I didn't understand what type of input it asking for.
Thank you

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question, and without proper code it is hard to say what you are doing.

Comment: I figure it out, so for the real time recognition I am running only 10 frame and saving an image to disk and reading it as the fist layer of inception is a DecodeJpeg.
Thank you so much :)